# Price Rules Free Shipping problems

Tags: magento-1.9, price, shipping, rules

Is there anyway to **configure Magento's Price rules** so that if Free shipping is given for purchases which in total are **equal to or greater than X AND if a coupon reduces X to a lesser value** customer pays for **shipping**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

override magento core model `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate`

just replace `getPackageValue()` with `getPackageValueWithDiscount()` in `collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)`

add below function

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
        }
    }

    // Free shipping by qty
    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        $freePackageValue = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                        $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
            }
        }
        $oldValue = $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount();
        $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
    }

    if ($freePackageValue) {
        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() - $freePackageValue);
    }
    if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
        $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
        $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_default_condition_name);
    }

    // Package weight and qty free shipping
    $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
    $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

    $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

    $result = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $rate = $this->getRate($request);

    $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

    if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
        $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty)) {
            $shippingPrice = 0;
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
        }

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

        $result->append($method);
    } elseif (empty($rate) && $request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
        /**
         * was applied promotion rule for whole cart
         * other shipping methods could be switched off at all
         * we must show table rate method with 0$ price, if grand_total more, than min table condition_value
         * free setPackageWeight() has already was taken into account
         */
        $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
        $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);
        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice(0);
            $method->setCost(0);

            $result->append($method);
        }
    } else {
        $error = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }

    return $result;
}
```